# Form binding with ModelAttribute throws BadRequest when some parameters are null

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring form data binding with @ModelAttribute. I have some hidden fields in the form which I need to populate after a request has been posted. These are some of my observations:

1) If these hidden fields have default values, the data from the form is bound correctly

2) If the hidden fields don't have values, a BadRequest is thrown by the server

3) If I remove the ModelAttribute binding in the controller, I am able to send the hidden fields with null, but I have to retrieve each parameter separately using request.getParameter()

Question: Is there any work-around using @ModelAttribute using which I can send null values for some of the form data? (e.g. values like sequence id, last updated time etc)

This issue is seen for any form parameters that are null - so any optional form values that can be left empty also give a "BadRequest" when using @ModelAttribute for form binding

Also, thought I'd mention that I'm using ajax to send the request (I read somewhere not to use @ModelAttribute when using ajax, not sure if its valid)

Thanks.

Comment: What type did you bind the field into?

Comment: string and date types

Comment: hi @kinf1 were you able to find solution for passing null in some of the form fields, I am also having same issue Bad request

Answer (score 0):

You can try in dis way using spring form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<div class="body-wraper">
  <section class="wrap">
    <h1><spring:message code="applicant.enrollment.module.label"/></h1>

    <form:form id="frmNetwrkSubscripInfo" method="post" modelAttribute="applicantDto">
    <form:hidden path="applicantId" id="hiddenApplicantId" value="" />
    <form:hidden path="paInd" id="hiddenPaInd" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" value = "${applicantDto.applProgressCde}" id ="applProgressCde"/>

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValidateText" value="<spring:message code='applicant.network_subscription.promocode.button.label.validate' />" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Having empty form values also returns a BadRequest from the server (when @ModelAttribute is used)